# How do I say something past/back in future?

Tags: past-tense, future-tense, future-perfect

I want to say something about future. But then, since that *something* does not exist, I want to refer it to the *past!* How do I say that?

> 10 amazing futuristic things I wish ***were*** real **or** 
>  10 amazing futuristic things I wish ***will be*** real

For example, I'm creating a hypothetical situation of having some unbelievable features in a smart gadget of future. Say -using a smartphone, you can disappear! Using a smartphone, you can actually shoot at someone. Using a smartphone, you can even fly!

How do I say that then?

> Three futuristic smartphone features I wish ***will be*** real **OR**
> Three futuristic smartphone features I wish ***were*** real **OR**
>  Three futuristic smartphone features I wish ***will have been*** real

Answer (score 1):

"Were" is used here in the **subjunctive** mood, referring to an event that is not likely or is untrue; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood.

*futuristic things I wish were real* is acceptable, meaning they don't currently exist but you wish they did exist **now**.

*futuristic things I hope will be real* is how I would phrase the second, though *wish* might be acceptable, too. It implies a hope for the **future**.

So my vote is for **"Three futuristic smartphone features I wish were real,"** if by that you mean you want those features **now**, but they don't exist.

If you plan on making that phone, though, then it **will have** those features.

Comment: I think we cannot say "will have" in the subjunctive mood. instead, it should be "would have".

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, these are futuristic features that you wish existed now, then you would say, "Ten futuristic smart phone features I wish were real."

If you mean that you hope these will be invented in the future ... well, you probably would say "hope" rather than "wish", so you'd say ... "Ten futuristic smart phone features that I hope will be real." You'd probably also add some time frame, like "that I hope will be real within the next decade" or at least "that I hope will be real someday."

We don't normally say, "I wish this will happen". If there's a grammar rule that breaks, I'm not sure what it is, but no one says that. Rather we say, "I hope this will happen" or "I wish this would happen."